# How to get parameter in CoffeeScript event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

How does one go about accessing the parameters of an event handler in CoffeeScript?

I have created a color picker widget in Dashing (http://dashing.io).
The color picker is based on Spectrum (https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/#events), and publishes an onchange event with a color parameter.

When the user clicks a color in the palette, the color name/code is generated on the front-end by the Spectrum color picker widget.

Here's an excerpt of what the existing colorpicker code looks like:

```
change: function(color) {
    color.toHexString(); // i.e. #ff0000
}
```

The implementation guide of the color picker is here:
https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/#events

In my coffeescript file, I have

```
$(@node).on 'change', (evt) => @handleChanged evt

  postState: (newState) ->
    $.post '/openhab/dispatch',
      deviceId: @get('device'),
      command: newState

  handleChanged: (evt) ->
    @postState("test")
```

I would like to be able to access the color parameter of the Spectrum color picker in the handleChanged function, and pass it on to the postState function in place of the "test" placeholder.

Feel free to criticise - I am 100% lost when it comes to this high-level Coffeescript, Ruby on Rails environment, as I usually work in C, at register level on embedded devices.

Comment: Further to Pradeep's answer, the color value is generated on the client side by the Spectrum widget. Here is the code: 
    hide: function(color) {
        color.toHexString(); // #ff0000
    }

Answer (score 0):

**Not Possible directly**

As I have understood this is not possible. Because assets or coffee script compiler is not associated with rails engine so you can get variables form your application.

**There are two methods that you can handle it**

1. Instead of using format.html use format.js in your action for giving response to user and then in your action.js.erb file write your javascript where you can get all variables.
2. Save variable from application in cookies and access them in coffee script.

Comment: Thanks Pradeep, but the color variable is generated in jQuery on the client side by the Spectrum widget, and not in rails.